# Qt build catalogue be changed in CMake Build Configuration

Tags: qt, build, configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9xUf.png)

Because I deleted my build fold, so I wanted to create a new build fold, but I couldn't succeed.
But I remember that in QMake Environment, the behavior is no problem, but in CMake Evironment,it's wrong now.
Please help me.